# How to do elasticsearch aggregation together with sort and find duplicate values

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I want to find duplicate values and if there are duplicate values then I sort based on the last update, so what I take is the newest one, how do I do aggregations? I've tried this aggregation.

I've tried adding sort to sources but it still doesn't work, I've tried several ways but it still fails sometimes it comes out 1 but only old data, sometimes the order is correct from the newest but appears 2 data

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "BILLING_TYPE_CD": "Service Bundle"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "ID": "xxxx"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "LI_MILESTONE"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "LI_SID"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "LI_SID",
            "query": "*xxxx*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "LI_PRODUCT_NAME",
                "query": "*Network*"
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "LI_MILESTONE.keyword": [
                  "Abandoned",
                  "Cancelled"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "ORDER_STATUS.keyword": [
                  "Abandoned",
                  "Cancelled",
                  "Drop In Progress"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "STATUS.keyword": ""
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "TGL_CREATED": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "list_products": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 50000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "LI_SID": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "LI_SID.keyword",
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "totalService": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "LI_SID.keyword",
            "size": 50000,
            "order": {
              "_term": "asc"
            }
          }
        },
        "bucket_sort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "includes_source": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "LAST_UPDATE",
                "xxxxx",
                "xxxxx",
                "xxxxx",
                "xxx"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "term_product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "LI_SID.keyword",
        "size": 50000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: @ESCoder

this sample index data and expected result.

https://pastebin.com/raw/QyL9AkQ2

at this sample its have two data and with same LI_SID and different date time, how to get one from this duplicate LI_SID and just get the newest value from LAST_UPDATE

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "LI_SID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "LI_SID.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hit": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "LAST_UPDATE": "desc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

You need to use `aggregations` response not `hits`